# OBIEE Moving Average (Mavg) for 4 weeks on Pivot Table

Tags: obiee

Is it possible to calculate the moving average for 4 weeks in a separate column within the pivot shown here.

This is what I have:

http://i58.tinypic.com/2rraweo.jpg

Needs to have additional columns like:

http://i59.tinypic.com/30ti8ok.jpg

Side note: This is a union report and the "Total # of Submitted SRs" column is a sum measure from a fact table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was the function MAVG("column", 4) as long as the rows are defined by each week's count of "Total # of Submitted SRs".

Comment: I have a similar question and was hoping you could answer from having done this: I have a bunch on data from individual actions. In a pivot table I combined the actions by week. I want to do a moving average by **week**. Is there a way to to the moving average within the pivot table specifically? If so how?