# Calculated Item in OBIEE - Moving Average

Tags: oracle, pivot-table, moving-average, obiee

I have consulted this question - [OBIEE Moving Average (Mavg) for 4 weeks on Pivot Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30404092/obiee-moving-average-mavg-for-4-weeks-on-pivot-table?rq=1) - in order to understand how to do a moving average in OBIEE. However, I am having trouble calculating that item in a pivot table.

In the pivot table view I thought I would just select `New Calculated Item` and create my moving average function for the pivoted values. Yet, in the "Values From" drop down menu the items I want to average are not present. I believe this may be because they are not extracted data values but previously calculated values from the data (in the original table's columns). I tried selecting "treat as attribute column" but this failed as well. **How can I created a moving average within the pivot table for a column that was calculated from the original data?**

Looks similar to this:

```
Pivot Table
ID    Value
01    45
02    54
03    65
...   ...
```

Where `Value` is `Amount Sold / Days`. And both `Amount Sold` and `Days` are stored in the original data table.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the criteria tab and pull in a measure (any measure will do). Now edit that measure's column formula to your formula of `Amount Sold / Days`. I would rename it as well.

When you click over to the results tab, you will see that column added to all views. Just edit each view and remove the column from the views you do not want to see it in. You can also replace your existing value column in your pivot table (if it was present) with this new calculated column.

Pivot table calculated items are typically used in conjunction with columns that are already in the pivot table.

Comment: Should I put in the moving average formula of MAVG("column",4) in the new measure column of the criteria tab?

Comment: I would think that your column formula would need whatever moving average formula you have.

Comment: The problem that occurs is that my original data is in individual periods - multiple a day. In the moving average I want that across the average of each week. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: I would try the `PERIODROLLING` function. See more about that here: http://gerardnico.com/wiki/dat/obiee/function_time. This I believe lets you select from your hierarchy the time frame you want the rolling average to be for.